# Can someone explain the parameter void(*pfn)(void*)?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I've come across this piece of code

```
inline pthread_t CreateThread(void(*pfn)(void*), void* parg, bool fWantHandle=false)
```

I don't understand this part

```
void(*pfn)(void*)
```

Can someone tell me what it means/is?

This is btw not listed in books for beginners so if you want to mention to read books, it's not there.

Afaik, void is datatype of a function meaning it will not return anything, however that part there...void is used on a pointer?

Comment: This should be listed in any decent book.  However, there is no easy way to find it if you don't already know what it is.

Comment: Function pointer syntax in C and C++ is really nasty, if you ask me.

Comment: Good question - this is what SO is all about

Comment: [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is a function pointer (or a pointer to a function).**

```
void(*pfn)(void*)
```

This is broken down as such:

`*pfn` (the name of the pointer i.e. pointer to a function)

`(void *)` (these are the parameters to the function ie. a simple pointer to anything)

`void` (this is return from the function)

So if you have a function like this:

```
void DoSomeThing(void *data) {
  ... does something....
}
```

then you can pass it into the `CreateThread` function like so...

```
int i  = 99;
void * arg = (void*)&i;
pthread_t thread = CreateThread(DoSomeThing, arg, ... other parameters ...);
```

So somewhere in `CreateThread` it will make a call:

```
pfn(parg);
```

and your function DoSomeThing will be called and `void * data` you get will be the arg you passed in.

**More info:**

Remember that code is just a sequence of bytes in memory. It's just how the cpu interprets them that makes them different from the thing we call data.

So at any point in a program we can refer to another part of the code by it's memory address. Since the code is broken down into functions with in C, this is a useful unit of reuse that C understands and allows us to treat the address of the function as just another pointer to some data.

In the above example the CreateThread function needs the address of a function so it can execute that function in a new thread. So we pass it a pointer to that function. Hence we pass it a *function pointer*.

Answer (score 9):

It's a function pointer to a function returning `void` and accepting `void *`.

```
void example(void *arg);
```

You can find more information about function pointers in C++ (and in C) at [The Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

These things are easiest read inside out:

- `(*pfn)` => "`pfn` is a pointer"
- `void x(void*)` => "`x` is a function accepting a `void *` argument and returning `void`"

Put them together and you have:

- "`pfn` is a pointer to a function accepting a `void *` argument and returning `void`"

Note that the parens around `(*pfn)` are necessary because of precedence. `void *pfn(void*)` would be interpreted as if it were written `(void *)pfn(void *)`: "`pfn` is a function that accepts a `void *` and returns a `void *`".

Comment: The "Note" is considerate.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a [*function pointer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).
It points to a function rather than a variable.

If it isn't in your book, you should get a better book.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [function pointer](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html) returning nothing and taking a [void pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) (see the section called *void pointers*).

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `CreateThread` says that the first parameter `pfn` is a pointer to a callback function that will be used by `CreateThread`. The callback `pfn` is your own function that `CreateThread` will call so that you can execute your code in a new thread.

You define a function

```
void MyThreadCallback(void* data)
{
    MyData myData = reinterpret_cast<MyData*>(data);
    ...
}
```

and pass it to `CreateThread` as

```
MyData* myData = new MyData();
CreateThread(MyThreadCallback, myData, ... );
```

so that `CreateThread` can call it in the context of the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

`pfn` is a function pointer whose return type is **void** and argument's type is **void***

Answer (score 1):

It is a function pointer. The name pfn is a clue. Specifically it is a pointer to a function that takes a "void pointer" and returns nothing. A "void pointer" is a fake type that can be cast to some other kind of pointer.

Most C++ books cover both void pointers and function pointers in some detail. Probably more detail than necessary, since you can write perfectly good C++ code without ever using either. If your books are somehow all super modern and don't cover them, look for a C reference.